# How do I wait for all work to be completed before closing the channel?

Tags: go

I am creating an email sending application in Go.

I have encountered a problem when an email could not be sent successfully. In these cases, I want to return the email in a go channel, but the channel is closed.

How I can prevent the channel being closed before all tasks have completed?

This is the function with this problem:

```
func worker(toSend chan combo, tried chan combo, s smptInfo, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for try := range toSend {

        startSend := time.Now()
        delegate := make(chan bool, 1)
        go sendEmailSSH(try, delegate, s, try.line)
        select {
        case res := <-delegate:
            if res == true {
                try.success = res
                tried <- try
            } else {
                toSend <- try // if send not successfull return back to channel
            }
        case <-time.After(smtpTimeout):
            toSend <- try // if send timeout return back to channel
        }

        Pauza(startSend) // if send more fast like limit send, wait.
    }

    wg.Done()
}
```

The complete application can be found on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/obreja/c960e3e672297de28fd9ae397303b272).

Comment: With channels, it can be good to have only one place from where things are sent. This way it. sending to a closed channel can easily be avoided as the only sender knows if the channel is open, as it is his responsibility to close to it. In your case, this could be archived by adding another "sender" goroutine, which as 2 channels from which it receives (e.g. `sendQueue` and `failed`) and one channel to which it forwards everything (e.g. `toSend`). You would then queue the emails in the `sendQueue` and failed emails would be sent to `failed`. When a sender is done, it can close its channel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I would suggest. I have removed few SMTP specific parts, for simplicity. You can plug them in again.

**1. Sample code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type combo struct {
    success bool
    toEmail string
}

func sendEmailSSH(try combo, delegate chan bool) {

    defer close(delegate)

    r := rand.Intn(7)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(r) * time.Second)
    if r%2 == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("sendEmailSSH: failing randomly after %d seconds: %+v\n", r, try)

        delegate <- false
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("sendEmailSSH: successful after %d seconds: %+v\n", r, try)

        delegate <- true

    }

}

func sendEmailSSHWrapper(try combo, toRetry chan combo) {

    // do something with try
    delegate := make(chan bool, 1)
    smtpTimeout := 3 // if no success within 3 seconds, mark it as failed

    go sendEmailSSH(try, delegate)


    go func() {
                select {
        case res := <-delegate:
            if res == true {
                try.success = res
            } else {
                toRetry <- try // if send not successfull, add to retry channel
            }
        case <-time.After(time.Duration(smtpTimeout) * time.Second):
            fmt.Printf("sendEmailSSHWrapper: failing due to timeout: %+v\n", try)

            toRetry <- try // if send timeout, add to retry channel
        }

    }()

}

// where we actually do the work
func worker(toSend chan combo, wg *sync.WaitGroup, id int) {

    toRetry := make(chan combo, 5)
    retryDone := false

    for try := range toSend {
        go sendEmailSSHWrapper(try, toRetry)
    }

    for !retryDone {
        select {

        case try, ok := <-toRetry:
            if !ok {
                log.Println("toRetry is already closed")
                retryDone = true
                continue
            }
            fmt.Printf("worker %d: picking up %+v for retry\n", id, try)
            go sendEmailSSHWrapper(try, toRetry)
        case <-time.After(time.Duration(15) * time.Second):
            fmt.Printf("worker %d: no data in toRetry(%d) channel for 15 seconds. closing toRetry now\n", id, id)
            close(toRetry)
            toRetry = nil
            retryDone = true
        }

    }

    wg.Done()
}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup // keep track of the workers

    toSend := make(chan combo) // to the workers

    // emailList := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"}
    emailList := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}


    // initialize n workers

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(toSend, &wg, i)
    }

    var count int = 0

    for i := 0; i < len(emailList); i++ {
        count++
        toSend <- combo{toEmail: emailList[i], success: false}
    }

    close(toSend)
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Send emails Done!")
}
```

Try it here:
https://play.golang.org/p/W7ur2wr3HeD

**2. What I have done:**

1. Whenever main is done adding data, it should close the `toSend` channel. It won't be used any further.
2. Create a wrapper over sendEmailSSH function. Your current implementation of calling `go sendEmailSSH(try, delegate, s, try.line)` is not very optimised, as after starting the go routine, it is anyways blocked on a unary sized channel, which is as good as a serial call.
3. Alternatively, I have called `go sendEmailSSHWrapper(try, toRetry)`, and it internally calls actual `sendEmailSSHWrapper` function & monitors delegate channel.
4. `sendEmailSSH` randomly fails few requests, for the purpose of demonstration.
5. `sendEmailSSHWrapper` monitors `delegate` it's own channel for failures, and also checks for timeout (I kept it 3 seconds for demonstration)
6. Worker first completely exhausts the `toSend` channel. And then moves to `toRetry` channel. It works on it, unless it sees no data on this channel for 15 seconds(again, kept high for demonstration)

**3. What you will need to add:**

1. You should really implement some mechanism so that you retry only a given number of times for any given email address. Or else, you might be stuck in the for loop forever, for any faulty email address, or any unexpected scenario (multiple continuous timeouts due to latency), maybe using a map to track counts of retried entries. Or even simpler, add a `retryCount int` to your `combo` struct, and increment it with every retry, and check before retrying every time.
2. Note that in both your and my approach, we are retrying on timeout. Are you sure if timeout happens, email will never be delivered? If not, you should really be using `context with cancellation`, or someway to kill the actual go routine if it takes more time, before retrying. Else, on some bad day, if the latency is more, you might end up timing out a lot, and keep retrying. While in reality you would be spamming the user with a lot of emails.

Comment: The approach you are describing is reasonable, but I see a problem with it. If I am not mistaken, a `for` loop over a channel only stops when `break` is used or the channel is closed. Now the problem in your approach is, that the channel will only be closed, once the for loop finishes, which only happens once the channel is closed. This would lead to a deadlock. Also, I think you have a typo in what needs to be changed, as the 2 code blocks are identical (from the rest of the answer, I'd guess you want to swap the 2 lines in the first code block).

Comment: Ohhh.. yes, thanks for pointing out. Will update the answer in some time. Will post with a working code. It's easy to miss such things without writing actual code. My statement "only this change is needed" was certainly wrong.

Comment: @Leon : Updated my answer with another approach.

Comment: That looks good and I only noticed 2 things: First, the timeout-select in `sendEmailSSHWrapper` is run inside the goroutine, meaning the timeout will start, once `sendEmailSSH` returns. Moving the select out of the goroutine would make it an actual timeout, instead of waiting for it to finish before starting the timeout.

Comment: Second, in `worker`, the only way the `toRetry` channel will be closed, it when the timeout happens. This means that checking `ok` is unnecessary, as. when the channel is closed, the loop will be broken. If that is not intentional, you would need to add a mechanism to close the channel, once all `sendEmailSSHWrapper` have returned (e.g. with a `sync.WaitGroup` which tracks all running `sendEmailSSHWrapper` and an additional goroutine, which waits for it to be `Done()` and then closes the channel.).

Comment: First one, Updated. Thanks.
About closing `retryChan`, tried few approaches.

`sync.WaitGroup` didn't look like a safe option when tried, as there were continuous `.Add(1)` & `.Done()` calls, and `.Add(1)` being called after `.Wait()`.

 I also tried checking for `len(retryChan)` and taking decision to close(retryChan) on basis of that. But same problem. There were go-routines still running, and they try to `send after close()`, causing a BOOM.

So to be on safe side, I suggested keeping a reasonably big enough timeout, and then `context` can be used if some go routine is still running.

Comment: My idea would look like the following: create a new WaitGroup before `range toSend` loop, add an `Add(1)` inside the loop, before starting the goroutine, `defer` the `Done()` call inside the goroutine and start a goroutine doing `Wait()` and then `close()` after the `range toSend` loop finishes ([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ze2REwhrU62)). This way, all `Add()` calls happen before the `Wait()` call, as we only start waiting once the `toSend` channel is closed. Maybe I missed something, but I don't see how this would `close` the channel before all `sendEmailSSHWrapper` are done.

Comment: Understood slightly, what you are trying to say. But your code ends up closing the `retryChan` right after `toSend` loop is done, and before we actually start with `retryChan`.
`sendEmailSSH: failing randomly after 0 seconds: {success:false toEmail:c}
toRetry is already closed
toRetry is already closed
worker 0: picking up {success:false toEmail:c} for retry
toRetry is already closed
toRetry is already closed
toRetry is already closed
Send emails Done!`
No retries actually happen.Though, I will try working on similar idea on the block that handles `retryChan`, once we see the OP again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180018/discussion-between-tushar-and-leon).